# JavaScript React Redux: Field from Database is not Rendering in Web Page and Can't Select Value in DropDown

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, components, render

I have a table with a field called isAdmin on the back-end.  The isAdmin field is either true or false for different users.

[image]

Below is my react/redux code that renders that front-end using the field names where applicable:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getUsers} from '../store/allUsers' // toDate
import {updateUserThunk, fetchSingleUser} from '../store/singleUser'
// Status Filter import BeerFilter from './BeerFilter'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import {UncontrolledCollapse} from 'reactstrap'

export class AllUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showForm: false,
      isAdmin: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.props.fetchInitialUsers()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  clickHandlerOne() {
    let hidden = this.state.showForm
    this.setState({
      showForm: !hidden
    })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    //console.log('event.target', event.target)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  async handleSubmit(userId) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const updatedUser = {
      id: userId,
      isAdmin: this.state.isAdmin
    }

    // console.log('UPDATE USER', updatedUser)

    await this.props.updateUserThunk(updatedUser)
    this.props.fetchInitialUsers()
  }

  render() {
    const users = this.props.users
    // console.log('PROPS', this.props)
    console.log('USERS', this.props.users)

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="options">
          <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="">Sort By...</option>
            <option value="priceHighToLow">Price (high to low)</option>
            <option value="priceLowToHigh">Price (low to high)</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
          </select>

          <BeerFilter />
          </div> */}

        <div className="flex-cards">
          {users.map(user => (
            <Card style={{width: '18rem'}} key={user.id}>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>User Id: {user.id}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <div className="highlight">
                          <img src={user.imageUrl} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                          <p>Username: {user.username}</p>
                          <p>User Email: {user.email}</p>
                          <p>Admin Status: {user.isAdmin}</p>
                          <p>
                            Created Date:{' '}
                            {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
                              month: 'short',
                              day: '2-digit',
                              year: 'numeric'
                            }).format(new Date(user.createdAt))}
                          </p>
                          <p />
                          <Button
                            id={`user${user.id}`}
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.clickHandlerOne()
                            }}
                            variant="danger"
                          >
                            Admin Status Toggle
                          </Button>
                          <UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#user${user.id}`}>
                            {/* {this.state.showForm && (
                              <UpdateUserStatus userId={user.id} />
                            )} */}
                            <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(user.id)}>
                              <div>
                                <span>
                                  <select
                                    name="isAdmin"
                                    value={
                                      typeof user.isAdmin === 'string'
                                        ? this.state.isAdmin
                                        : user.isAdmin
                                    }
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                  >
                                    <option value="true">true</option>
                                    <option value="false">false</option>
                                  </select>
                                </span>

                                <p />
                                <span>
                                  <p>
                                    {/* */}
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                  </p>
                                </span>

                                {/* delete thunk
                                <span>
                                  <p>
                                    <button type="button">Delete</button>
                                  </p>
                                </span>
                                */}
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </UncontrolledCollapse>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    users: state.allUsers
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadSingleUser: id => dispatch(fetchSingleUser(id)),
    updateUserThunk: updatedUser => dispatch(updateUserThunk(updatedUser)),
    //getSortedBeers: (sortBy, beers) => dispatch(sortBeers(sortBy, beers)),
    fetchInitialUsers: () => dispatch(getUsers())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllUsers)
```

I have two issues with trying to render the isAdmin field.  First, the true or false value associated with the isAdmin field never gets rendered.

See pic:

[image]

**Question 1: how can I get the value of isAdmin field to render?**

My second question is related to updating my isAdmin field and rendering the update on the web page.

After I click on the red toggle button, I have a drop down field where I can select true or false.  It is defaulted on the value "true" or "false" from the database.  But I can't seem to select the other drop down value.  It remains stuck on the default selection.

[image]

For example, the drop down defaulted on false.  When I open the drop down and select true, it doesn't select true ... it still has false selected.

**Question 2: What am I doing wrong?**

The end goal is to be able to select the opposite of what is defaulted in the dropdown and update my Admin Status to the selected status.

Answer (score 0):

1.`user.isAdmin` is a boolean false, React  does not render such value. You can fix this by rendering a string :

```
{user.isAdmin ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
```

2.When you render the `select` field, you use a condition in the value :

```
typeof user.isAdmin === 'string' ? this.state.isAdmin : user.isAdmin
```

because `user.isAdmin` is boolean, the value prop will always be `user.isAdmin`. You can fix this by using `this.state.isAdmin` directly :

```
value={this.state.isAdmin}
```

Comment: Mohamed, thank you so much for the response.  I've implemented the following: {user.isAdmin ? 'Yes' : 'No'} and typeof user.isAdmin === 'string' ? this.state.isAdmin : user.isAdmin from your suggestion

Comment: Followup from comment above:  the only issue I have now is as follows: when I open the toggle, let's say it defaults to true.  I select the dropdown and select false.  The drop down doesn't change to false ... it still stays at true.  But I click submit and then everything updates to false which is good.  But I want the dropdown to show false right after I select false ... any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer, change the select value like this : `value={this.state.isAdmin}`

Comment: I tried that previously, so instead of typeof user.isAdmin === 'string' ? this.state.isAdmin : user.isAdmin in the select value I used value={this.state.isAdmin} .... but when I do that and select a value from the dropdown and click submit... it doesn't send it to my state component --> isAdmin becomes ""